# spring data mongodb findByIdIn

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following data model

```
@Document
public class FormDocument
{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private LocalDateTime createTimestamp;
    ...
}
```

and spring data repository interface

```
public interface FormRepository extends MongoRepository<FormDocument, String>
{
    List<FormDocument> findByIdIn(List<String> ids, Pageable pageable);
}
```

But findByIdIn method returns an empty list even if ids exist in mongodb. I've tested findByXXXIn() for other fields in my document and they all work fine. But when it comes to document id it does not.

This is the first time I'm working with mongodb but I'm familiar with spring data jpa.

I know about

```
Iterable<T> findAll(Iterable<ID> ids);
```

but I also need to apply paging on the results so it's not helpful in my case.

I tried using @Query (with an in query) and also tried `List<ObjectId>` instead of `List<String>` but I wasn't successful.

So what am I missing ?

Comment: What is your requirement?? You want to get FormDocument by passing an Id, right? or more than one Ids will be passed at a time??

Comment: @pvpkiran Internally id will be mapped to _id.

Comment: In the database it's stored as _id but spring should handle the conversion. I have some other repository methods which reads a single or multiple form documents. And I can see the id fields set in the results.

Comment: @MehrajMalik I want to get a list of FormDocuments by providing a list of form ids. And I also want to be able to paginate.

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you add couple of document from your collection that you are expecting your query to return along with input values for list and pageble argument ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the id variable is not mapped to _id key. Please verify the import

A field annotated with @Id (org.springframework.data.annotation.Id) will be mapped to the '_id' field.

A field without an annotation but named id will be mapped to the '_id' field.

Comment: Import looks fine.